# Microsoft WPF Map Control - InvalidOperationException - "Cannot perform this operation while dispatcher processing is suspended."

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, bing-maps, invalidoperationexception

I have a WPF application built on .NET 4.5.  The latest version of the map control (version 1.0.1.0) is causing an issue if it is used within a datatemplate.  This does not happen with the previous version I was using from NuGet (version 1.0.0.0).    It is easy to reproduce the issue:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MicrosoftMapError.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Content="{Binding ViewModel,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
   <Window.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Views/MapView.xaml" />
         </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      </ResourceDictionary>
   </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.cs:

```
using MicrosoftMapError.ViewModels;
using System.Windows;

namespace MicrosoftMapError
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.ViewModel = new MapViewModel();
        }

        public object ViewModel
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ViewModel",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(MainWindow));
    }
}
```

MapView.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
                    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MicrosoftMapError.ViewModels">
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:MapViewModel}">
      <Grid>
         <wpf:Map />
      </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The MapViewModel class is just an empty class; there is nothing interesting to see there.

And this is the stack trace for the exceptions.

Outer exception:

```
XamlParseException - The invocation of the constructor on type 'Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Map' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlReader templateReader, XamlObjectWriter currentWriter)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlObjectWriter objectWriter)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadOptimizedTemplateContent(DependencyObject container, IComponentConnector componentConnector, IStyleConnector styleConnector, List`1 affectedChildren, UncommonField`1 templatedNonFeChildrenField)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadContent(DependencyObject container, List`1 affectedChildren)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, Int32 lastChildIndex, HybridDictionary childIndexFromChildID, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 templateDataField, FrameworkElement container)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverrideHelper(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(Visual value)
   at System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisual()
   at System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisualAndUpdateSTC()
   at System.Windows.Window.SetupInitialState(Double requestedTop, Double requestedLeft, Double requestedWidth, Double requestedHeight)
   at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean duringShow)
   at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowDuringShow()
   at System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindowDuringShow()
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at MicrosoftMapError.App.Main() in d:\SoftwareDevelopment\Working\MicrosoftMapError\MicrosoftMapError\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Inner exception:

```
InvalidOperationException - Cannot perform this operation while dispatcher processing is suspended.
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Wait(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherOperation operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Core.MapConfigurationFromWeb.ConfigLoaded(String requestKey, Dictionary`2 sections)
   at Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Core.MapConfigurationFromWeb.GetConfigurationSection(String version, String sectionName, String culture, MapConfigurationCallback callback, Boolean reExecuteCallback, Object userState)
   at Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Core.MapConfiguration.GetSection(String version, String sectionName, String culture, String key, MapConfigurationCallback callback, Boolean reExecuteCallback, Object userState)
   at Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Core.MapConfiguration.GetSection(String version, String sectionName, String culture, String key, MapConfigurationCallback callback, Boolean reExecuteCallback)
   at Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Map..ctor()
```

Comment: Why, on earth, are you creating a ViewModel property on your window?  The VM should be the DataContext of the window.

Comment: Also, you just might not be able to create that control in a resource....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are dev team has looked into this and I believe they have found the issue. They are working on putting together a new release. Also, Microsoft never officially released a Nuget package, someone just took some old buggy libraries and posted them on Nuget without asking Microsoft. We are planning to make an official Nuget package.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Is there somewhere I can follow this issue?  A ticketing system or something for Bing WPF Maps?

Comment: If you have an Enterprise Bing Maps license you can contact the Bing Maps Enterprise support team and they will create a ticket for this and be able to provide you with updates. That said, I believe the updated WPF control will be released in the next couple of weeks.

Comment: It looks like our team already pushed out the updated WPF control as a Nuget package here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF/ The original download page will likely be updated shortly.